# How to open bunch of .txt files in a one string via Python

Tags: python, file, text, directory

It's clear for me how to open one file and it's pretty straight forward by using `open()` function just like this:

```
with open('number.txt', 'rb') as myfile:
    data=myfile.read()
```

But what will be my actions if I want to open 5 .txt files and also view them as a string in Python? Should I somehow use `os.listdir()` possibilities?

Comment: Use a loop? Not quite sure what you're asking

Comment: What do you mean with a `one string`, you mean code in one line or have all the data concatenated in one string variable?

Comment: Concatenated in one string variable

Comment: provide an example of what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a flexible/reusable approach for doing exactly what you need:

```
def read_files(files):
    for filename in files:
        with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
            yield file.read()

def read_files_as_string(files, separator='\n'):
    files_content = list(read_files(files=files))
    return separator.join(files_content)

# build your files list as you need
files = ['f1.txt', 'f2.txt', 'f3.txt']
files_content_str = read_files_as_string(files)
print(files_content_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need.

```
import os
path = "your_path"
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if filename.endswith(".txt"):
        with open(os.path.join(path, filename), 'rb') as myfile:
            data=myfile.read()
```

Comment: only gives the result of one file in the folder which is strange